# Find particular data attribute from script tag and remove the script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some script tags in my html page. My question is how to remove particular data attribute from script tag

```
<script src="js/scripttest1" data-invalid= "true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scripttest2" data-invalid= "true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scripttest3" data-required= "true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want remove the data attribure 'data-invalid' in jquery on dom ready please help me regarding on this.

I tried:

```
$("script['data-invalid']").remove();
```

it not working please give proper solution how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$("script").removeAttr('data-invalid');
```

**Update**

> No i want script tag should be removed not the attribute

If you want to remove the script tag itself, do

```
$("script[data-invalid]").remove();
```

**without** the single quotes

Comment: No i want script tag should be removed not the attribute

Comment: your second  answer i  tried but it doesn't removed

Comment: @Tushar, he had a sytax error with the single quotes

Comment: @SudharsanSridharan, without the single quotes in $("script['data-invalid']") but like this $("script[data-invalid']")

Comment: Yes, I had a sytax error with the single quotes . AmmarCSE superman thanks

Comment: @SudharsanSridharan Removing script tag doesn't remove the loaded script (if loaded without unhandled error) from browser memory so this doesn't make much sense

Comment: Wait a bit time I will approved your answer

Comment: @A.Wolff - it is dynamically loaded i don't want it

Comment: @SudharsanSridharan Sorry, i don't understand what you mean by dynamically loaded. If you mean you check attribute of script loaded from e.g a ajax request content before adding it to the DOM, then ya it makes sense

Comment: My third party some plugins dynamically loaded the script tag in my html page. I didn't know how they loaded in my html.